# Can mAP(mean average precision) use at classification problem?

Tags: classification, evaluation-functions

I have some questions about mAP(mean Average Precision).

In object detection problem, mAP use to measure performance broadly.

But, Is it possible to use mAP in multi-class classification problem?

I read this [webpage](https://towardsdatascience.com/map-mean-average-precision-might-confuse-you-5956f1bfa9e2) to learn mAP. Then I think mAP can use multi-class classification problem, because detection problem use IoU for decide False positive(FP) or True Positive(TP). But classification problem also can decide TP or FP without using IoU, right?

So if that idea is true, then we can get recall and precision score in classification problem. Then we can plot precision-recall curve, then we can calculate AP by taking the area under the PR curve!

So I think mAP can also use at classification problem, but I can't find using mAP score in classification problem. Is my idea are false?

Thank you.

===edited===

I found some [link](https://fangdahan.medium.com/calculate-mean-average-precision-map-for-multi-label-classification-b082679d31be) to explain multi-class mAP, but I'm not sure that this methods are true.

Because, I can't understand in **Average Precision (AP)** paragraph. Why he said `class a, the possible recalls are T=1 (see here for why we ignore T=2 and T=3)` and `class b, the possible recalls are T=2, T=3`. I can't understand that how to pick a **T** value.